# Convert a scala list of Strings into a list of Doubles while discarding unconvertable strings

Tags: scala

I'm trying to parse a list of strings into a numeric format, while ignoring anything that can't be parsed. This is my attempt, but I can't help but think it's a common enough pattern that there must be a better way than having to call 2 maps and a filter. Can someone suggest a more canonical way of doing this? Perhaps using a partial function of some kind? Thanks!

```
val stringList = List("1","2","foo","4")
val parsed = stringList.map(s => scala.util.Try(s.toDouble)).filter(_.isSuccess).map(_.get)
```

Output:

```
stringList: List[String] = List(1, 2, foo, 4)
scala> parsed: List[Double] = List(1.0, 2.0, 4.0)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`flatMap` helps:

```
scala>  List("1","2","foo","4").flatMap(s => scala.util.Try(s.toDouble).toOption)
res0: List[Double] = List(1.0, 2.0, 4.0)
```

Comment: That's it. I didn't think of converting to Option, and was headscratching at why flatMap couldn't flatten a Try.

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that exceptions slow you down a lot.  So though the `Try` approach works, if most things are not numbers, it won't work very quickly.

You can write a regex to pick out things that might be doubles:

```
val D = """(-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)(?:[eE]?[+-]?[0-9]+)?)""".r
```

Then you will only try to parse things that are actually doubles:

```
val xs = List("1", "2", "foo", "4")
xs.collect{
  case D(x) => x.toDouble
  case "NaN" => Double.NaN
  case "Infinity" => Double.PositiveInfinity
  case "-Infinity" => Double.NegativeInfinity
}
```

Depending on application, it's about 10-60x faster when there are a substantial number of non-Double entries (e.g. 1/4 like in your example).

Comment: Very good point, thanks! I ended up doing a variant of this in my production code for this use case.

Answer (score 3):

Use `collect` and pattern-matching:

```
scala> List("1", "2", "foo", "4")
         .map(s => Try(s.toDouble))
         .collect { case Success(x) => x }

res3: List[Double] = List(1.0, 2.0, 4.0)
```

Comment: If I could accept two answers, I'd accept this one too! Very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using a for comprehension you can achieve the desired results, like this

```
for { 
  x <- xs
  v <- Try(x.toDouble).toOption
} yield v
```

Note those `v` that evaluate to `None` are not yielded.